# Global View Styes in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, crash

Why does my application keep crashing when i add this in my AppDelegate?:

```
// Change Global Style of the UINavigationBar
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:12.0/255.0 green:109.0/255.0 blue:216.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

// Chnage Global TabBar Color w/ Options
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor orangeColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:12.0/255.0 green:109.0/255.0 blue:216.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Am i supposed to do this in each VC instead of the AppDelegate?

Everything Compiles, but the App crashes with this error in the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Illegal property type, c for appearance setter, _installAppearanceSwizzlesForSetter:
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and tell us which line causes the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIAppearance` methods (`[SomeClass appearance]`) take affect for all controls of that type. You only need to declare them once, and then any new controls created will take on that style.

However, not all properties can be used with `UIAppearance`. Translucency is one of them, and so those calls to `setTranslucent:` are the cause of your crash. You can see this yourself if you look at the `UINavigationBar` header - `translucent` doesn't have the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` annotation. You'll have to set your translucency on your specific navigation bar instances.

Comment: How would i still do that in the AppDelegate?

Comment: It depends on how your views / viewcontrollers are created. If for example you create a navigationController in your AppDelegate, then you could just set its navigation bar's translucency: `[navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES]`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the latest Xcode & iOS (5 & 7) but you are trying to run it on a simulator with lower iOS version, ie 6.x.

The main reason of your crash could be setBarTintColor which is not there in iOS version earlier than 7.0

I hope that helps.